# Cleanest way to pass optional parameters in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-operator

I am using the "mongodb" driver for nodejs. I am trying to add an optional parameter for ttl to this existing method:

```
public async createIndex(index: any, unique: boolean): Promise<void> {
    await this.collection.createIndex(index, { unique });
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it than this:

```
public async createIndex(index: any, unique: boolean, ttl: number): Promise<void> {
    await ttl ? this.collection.createIndex(index, { unique, ttl }) : this.collection.createIndex(index, { unique });
}
```

I read that [passing null to an optional parameter](https://medium.com/@kgrvr/typescript-functions-optional-parameters-b245e7a06d7d) can make it act weirdly.

Comment: Is that a problem to call `createIndex(index, { unique, ttl })` with `ttl` undefined? With strict null checks available you won't be able to pass `null` to optional parameter (`, ttl?: number`)

Answer (score 3):

To make it cleaner, you can pass in an object with options (unique & ttl) for mongodb.

```
public async createIndex(index: any, opts: { unique: boolean, ttl?: number }): Promise<void> {
    await this.collection.createIndex(index, opts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to conditionally define the property inline:

```
public async createIndex(index: any, unique: boolean, ttl: number) {
    await this.collection.createIndex(index, {
      unique,
      ...(ttl ? { ttl } : {})
    });
}
```

Note that there's no need to note the return value if TS can infer it automatically. (You can if you want, but in most cases it doesn't help.)

Another option would be to define the parameter with the conditional operator, either ahead of time or inline inside the parameter list:

```
public async createIndex(index: any, unique: boolean, ttl: number) {
    const param = ttl ? { unique, ttl } : { ttl };
    await this.collection.createIndex(index, param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no need to check param "ttl"

```
public async createIndex(index: any, unique: boolean, ttl?: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.collection.createIndex(index, { unique, ttl });
}
```

The code "{ unique, ttl }" means "{ unique: unique, ttl: ttl }", when "ttl" is undefined, the result will be "{ unique: unique, ttl: undefined }", no error